# How to use css hover on a element and its parent container?

Tags: css

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63jj4p12/).
The HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="subDiv">hover me</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.myDiv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255,166,9,0.1);
}

.subDiv{
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subDiv:hover{
    color: #ffa609;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.subDiv:hover.myDiv{
    border: 5px solid rgba(255,166,9,1);    
}
```

What I want is:

 The color of text and orange border will be changed when text is hovered.

My solution is:

```
.subDiv:hover{
    color: #ffa609;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.subDiv:hover.myDiv{
    border: 5px solid rgba(255,166,9,1);    
}
```

It seems that only the first hover is working. Could someone tell me why or other solutions? (Pure CSS please)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/63jj4p12/2/

Parent selector is not there in css

Instead you can use this on hover of the parent div change its style

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 166, 9, 0.1);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.subDiv {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.myDiv:hover .subDiv {
  color: #ffa609;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.myDiv:hover {
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 166, 9, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="subDiv">hover me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a solution to put them together with one hover?

Comment: the new edition is not good as previous one. because I want to change color when only text is hovered.

Comment: `subDiv` is full block with a `width` of `200px` and when you hover anywhere it will change the text color

Answer (score 0):

Divs are `display: block` by default and will expand to take up their parents width. To have the text turn orange only when the text itself is hovered:

- make the `.subDiv` `display: inline` (Depending on your needs, it may be better for this div to be another element such as `<a>`)
- center it with `text-align: center` on the parent
- change the text color to orange only when the child is hovered:

  ```
  .myDiv .subDiv:hover {
     color: #ffa609;
  }
  ```

Then change the border color of the parent div when it is hovered. Hovering any of its children elements will maintain the hover state:

```
.myDiv:hover {
   border: 5px solid rgba(255, 166, 9, 1);
}
```

### Complete Example

Notice how the transition is on the `.myDiv` and it's child inherits the same behaviour with `transition: inherit`.

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 166, 9, 0.1);
  transition: all 1s;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.subDiv {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  transition: inherit;
}
.myDiv .subDiv:hover {
  color: #ffa609;
}
.myDiv:hover {
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 166, 9, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="subDiv">hover me</div>
</div>
```